# Error finding msaccess driver on windows parallel on a mac

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, parallels

I'm using pyodbc to acces a MSaccess database using python 2.7. I'm running windows 7 on parallels v10 on osx10.9. I'm using the following code to test it:

```
DBfile = 'c:\\dir\\testdb.db' 
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
```

and it cannot seem to locate the MSAccess driver, resulting in the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Projects/DBtest.py",
> line 6, in <module>
>     conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile) Error: ('HY024', "[HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path.  Make sure
> that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to
> the server on which the file resides. (-1023) (SQLDriverConnect);
> [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning
> Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process
>  0x590 Thread 0xa50 DBC 0x2c9389c Jet'. (1); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key
> 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x590 Thread 0xa50 DBC
> 0x2c9389c Jet'. (1); [HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
> '(unknown)' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is
> spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which
> the file resides. (-1023)")
```

I can't see anything else on SO that covers this issue but I'm new to ODBC and fairly new to SO so apologies if I've overlooked anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Does `os.path.isfile(DBfile)` return `True`?

Comment: hmmm no. The mdb file is in the same folder as the .py script. Removing the file path seems to have fixed the problem. This wasn't an issue when running in OSX, is there a trick to get around this as the path won't be the same in my final version? I'm sorry I get the feeling I am missing something obvious here, if this is the case excuse my ignorance!